# where to find temporary internet files in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, storage, browser-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome: where is the location to save browse temporary files](https://superuser.com/questions/106771/chrome-where-is-the-location-to-save-browse-temporary-files)

where it is being stored? Does it store the flv files when I stream videos online?
I go here but all I see is 56 kb files. 
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is here (Win XP):

%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

There is 403MB in there.

Try browsing to `about:cache` and see what it lists