# Is there anyway to search the chrome cache files?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

When viewing

> ```
> chrome://cache/
> ```

Is there anyway to search the chrome cache files?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, [ChromeCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) is nifty freeware that allows you to view the cache with a bit more readability.

It has a "**Find**" feature as well:

[image]

Another method with a better searching function would be to open the cache in **[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)**.

Save the cache by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> once on the page, then open the saved .html file in Notepad++.

[image]

Notepad++'s searching:

[image]

Downside to using Notepad++, however, is that you'll see the cache in raw format.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably rather naive approach, but you could go to the [directory containing cached files](https://superuser.com/questions/106771/where-are-temporary-files-in-chrome-stored) and then search them using the file manager of your choice.

<sup>I hope I understood correctly that you actually want to search in the *contents* of the cache files.</sup>